# UITabBarController and selectedIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c

didSelectViewController is not being fired when selectedIndex is set programmatically on UITabBarController object, when tapping manually everything works fine.

Comment: you'll get better responses if you clean up your question and take the time to explain it in detail (or code.. since it's programming q/a site)

Answer (score 0):

From my current work, it seems selectedIndex is updated only if the tabbed view hasn't been loaded before - perhaps the same applies to the responder chain "the other way around".

You might have more luck by switching tabs using selectedItem, at least I can identify the correct tab in the viewWillAppear in a tab's viewcontroller using the Item, but not the Index.

For you, the most obvious "fix" would be to also invoke didSelectViewController in every piece of code that changes the Index.